# const correctness with const objects and member pointers, constructor vulnerability

Tags: c++, class, pointers, const-correctness

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() : i(0), ptr(&i) {}
    int i;
    int *ptr;
    void change_const (int x) const { *ptr=x; }
};

int main()
{
    const Test obj;
    obj.ptr = &obj.i; // error
    obj.change_const(99);
    return 0;
}
```

Although in `obj` `ptr` is of type `int *const`, the constructor can make him point to `i` of type `const int`. An explicit try to do this of course fails. Why does a constructor offer this vulnerability regarding const correctness? Other non directly obvious vulnerabilities like

```
int *ptr;
const int **c_ptr = &ptr; // error
const int c = 10;
*c_ptr = &c;
*ptr = 20; // because here change of c possible
```

are also well thought prevented.

Comment: C++ sometimes give you enough rope to hang yourself. Just do not write doggy code in the first place and play by the rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the constructor (or at least the initializer list if not the body of the ctor) needs to be able to write a value to `i`.

As it happens, the way C++ achieves this is to make `this` a pointer-to-non-const in the constructor (and destructor). Basically, the `const`-ness of `obj` doesn't commence until the constructor has finished executing. That's why the vulnerability exists, because of a straightforward but imperfect solution to the technical problem of how to construct `const`-qualified objects.

Perhaps it could in principle be done differently. I suppose you'd need a separate `const` version of the constructor in which the compiler applies different rules (just as normal member functions can be `const`), treating data members as `const` and therefore (1) allowing them to be initialized but not assigned, (2) forbidding the initialization of `ptr` from `&i` since the latter would have type `int const*`. C++ doesn't do this, and as a result it has this loophole that you've driven through. If it did do it, people would have more difficulty writing constructors in certain cases, so it's a design trade-off.

Be aware that similarly a `volatile`-qualified object is not `volatile` in its own constructor or destructor.

Comment: Yes I thought also about these possibilities of a separate `const` version of the constructor, but I think theoretically it would be best, to have only something like your point (2): changing the meaning of operator `&` to return a `const *type` of a (member) variable having `type`. Regarding point (1), `this` should really stay non-const until constructor finishs to allow complex assignments like jogojapan mentioned (loops, ...). So only another meaning of `&` inside a extra `const`-constructor could stop this vulnerability? Maybe?

Comment: @mb84: Hmm, you'd have to be sure that meaning of `&` is both necessary and sufficient. If you want to allow `i = 1`, then people will expect `init(&i)` to be OK with `void init(int *p) { *p = 1; }`. You'd force them to use a `const_cast` in that case I suppose, but it's getting ugly. And it's not just pointers, the same issue applies to references. Presumably you'd forbid binding `i` to a non-const reference (even though it's a non-const lvalue) at the same time as making `&i` have type `const int*` (even though `i` is `int`). It's not pretty, which isn't to say it wouldn't work.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's not sufficient anyway, since it still allows someone to write `void setptr(Test *t) { t->ptr = &t->i; }`. Even if you make `&` magic inside the constructor, if `this` has type `Test*` then you don't prevent `setptr(this)`.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe 1. making `&` magic inside constructor, but not inside function calls (like your `init(&i)` upwards). 2. making `this` magic (= const) only inside function calls (like your `setptr(this)`) would do it. Not alowing to bind `i` to non-const references isn't even necessary since you would have to put an magic `&` before this alias.

Answer (score 4):

`const` is a language-level concept. That is, when you compile your code and execute it as machine code, all data is seen as data more or less. Note that I say "more or less" because we are ignoring the fact that, in theory, `const` data could be stored in read-only pages and trigger page faults when written to; but this is not common due to the granularity of page sizes. So what is happening is the following:

Your constructor initializes that value of `ptr` to point to the address of `i`. Since your `obj` object is `const`, you could not directly modify the value of `i` and, further, you could not change where `ptr` points to. However, you can access and manipulate the memory that `ptr` points to (in this case, the value of `i`).

Therefore, since the compiler doesn't check/know/care that `ptr` is pointing to `i`, it does not catch the violation of `const`. Instead, it just sees you modifying the data pointed to by `ptr`.

Comment: So the compiler doesn't/cannot respect/care about the type of `this` inside the constructor? `const Test *const this; this->ptr = &(this->i);`

Comment: @mb84: Yes, see Steve Jessop's response below. There are no guarantees about `const` until after the object has been initialized which is after a a single constructor for the object has finished execution.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Jessop answered it, but for what it's worth, here is the quote from the Standard (emphasis mine):

> 12.1/4 A constructor shall not be virtual (10.3) or static (9.4). A constructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. A constructor shall not be declared const, volatile, or const volatile (9.3.2). **const and volatile semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (1.8) ends.** A constructor shall not be declared with a ref-qualifier.

So `*this` is not a constant object from the point of view of the constructor, even when a constant object is created. This could have been designed differently, but then constructors of constant objects would be much less flexible than constructors of non-constant objects; for example, they would always have to initialize all members in the initializer list; they could not use loops etc. in the body of the constructor to set values for complex members.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, see also my comment at Steve Jessop. What do you think?

Comment: I think it would make some sense to have a const-version of the constructor, and allow only that to be used to initialize const objects. Now with uniform initialization syntax and move semantics, complex members can usually be initialized without a constructor body. Const objects are rare anyway. So I think if I were to redesign C++, I would make that proposal. But changing it now would obviously cause a lot of backward compatibility issues.